# Tracing PHPUnit mock object creation

Tags: php, unit-testing, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I am getting a PHPUnit test failure in my ZF2+Doctrine2 project:

```
RuntimeException: Method "findAllByState" could not be found in repository "Mock_EntityRepository_4af853d8"
```

I am creating the mock repository using:

```
$repository = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
$repository
       ->method('findAllByState')
       ->willReturn([]);
```

But that obviously is not correct.  So, **how do I trace the creation of the PHPUnit mock object to find out where `Mock_EntityRepository_blah` is being created, so that I can tell it about `findAllByState()`?**

Comment: you need `->setMethods(array('findAllByState'))` to be applied to mock builder. [more about it in documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects). A bit later after table 9.1

Comment: @xmike, thanks for that, but that test still errors out (not sure for what reason, see next) and also creates a `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getUnitOfWork() on null in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php on line 179` error, terminating PHPUnit, and preventing further output.

Comment: @xmike, ah because `setMethods()` overrides any defaults, so I need to tell it about `findBy` and `findAll` as well.  Thanks - that does solve my problem.  But I am still curious about the question I asked.

Comment: @xmike, would you like me to post my problem as a question so that you can answer it for the green tick?

Comment: i've never managed to look at mock generation with relevant depth and attention, but speaking broadly, PHPUnit analyzes actual class implementations, adds your configuration from that `getMockBuilder` stuff (or uses only your configuration if you mock an unexistent class), then generates the relevant code that would implement behaviour and spying capabilities, then `eval`'s it and instantiates it for you. You might want to examine [sources](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/blob/master/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php#L153) for the details.